# How to Prevent VBA written for one Excel workbook from affecting other workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have VBA function in excel as given below to pick values from corresponding cell in previous sheet. It works well when only this workbook (where this formula is present ) is open. If i open another excel workbooks eg.workbook2, this prevsheet function in first workbook picking up values from second workbook disturbing all values of first workbook. How can i modify this formula so that this function works/picks up values for this workbook instead of other opened workbooks.

```
Function PrevSheet(rCell As Range)
        Application.Volatile

        Dim i As Integer
        i = rCell.Cells(1).Parent.Index
        PrevSheet = Sheets(i - 1).Range(rCell.Address)
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this.

adding "ThisWorkbook" to following line of code

```
PrevSheet = Sheets(i - 1).Range(rCell.Address)
```

making it as

```
PrevSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i - 1).Range(rCell.Address)
```